# How to insert and retrieve images in MYSQL using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Is there a way to insert and retrieve images (the pic itself) in a MySQL Database using phpMyAdmin and XAMPP? I'm using C#.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this button will save my pic from the picturebox to the database
    String strAddress = " Data Source = 127.0.0.1; Initial Catalog= ex; user id = root; password= ''";
    MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection(strAddress);
    MySqlCommand sqlcomm = new MySqlCommand();

    sqlConn.Open();
    sqlcomm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ta VALUES(" + pictureBox1.Image  + "')";
    sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlcomm.Connection = sqlConn;
    sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("RECORD SAVED!", "SAVING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this will put an image in the picturebox 
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.Title = "Open Image";
    //dlg.Filter = "bmp files (*.bmp)|*.bmp";
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName);
    }
    dlg.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, have you attempted anything, searched google for answers? Stack Overflow is for specific problems, not how to write your entire application. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can answer questions about *specific* problems you are having while programming. You should show us what you've tried and where your problem is, using a Minimally-Complete-Verifiable-Example of your code.

Comment: What @GreenChili said. Also, the concept you're looking for is the BLOB -- binary large object.

Comment: Why would you even store images in MYSQL?

Comment: I tried to search for a code or the closest one but I failed. BTW it's not my entire application, just a part of it. I tried to post it here because I can't find any answer.

Comment: @Izzy my professor told us to do an application where as an admin you can add, edit, delete pictures using database.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its a very good idea to be storing images in the Database. However if that is your requirement then you can do something like

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Your Connection String"))
{
 string myQuery = "SELECT IMAGE FROM SOMETABLE";

    using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(myQuery, conn))
    {
       conn.Open();
       using(var reader = new cmd.ExecuteReader())
       {
         someVariable = (byte[])reader["IMAGE"];
       }
    }
}
```

This is assuming you have a column in your DB of datatype `BLOB`. Also you will need to install `Install-Package MySql.Data` package

Comment: Let us know how you get on

Comment: Noob question, why is your approach is different to mine?

Comment: Which part are you concerned about?

Comment: In my code above, I used 
       String strAddress = " Data Source = 127.0.0.1; Initial Catalog= ex; user id = root; password= ''";
        MySqlConnection sqlConn = new MySqlConnection(strAddress);
        MySqlCommand sqlcomm = new MySqlCommand();

        sqlConn.Open();
        sqlcomm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ta VALUES(" + pictureBox1.Image  + "')";
        sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        sqlcomm.Connection = sqlConn;
        sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConn.Close();

Comment: You can do it your way too. However it's recomennded to use the `using` blocks of connection because the connection autmatically gets disposed at the end of the `using` block so you don't need to do `con.Close` also the query in my example is a mock-up you can change it to your inert statement. However your insert statement should be paramertized. I used a reader assuming you'll be selecting a value but you'll use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` when inserting.

Comment: @Jacob Please don't forget to accept the solution if it was helpful so it can also benefit future readers

Answer (score 0):

You can store the actual images in the Database but it really isn't advisable.

Store images in directories and within your database store references to the images(eg the path to the image).

Images can be quite large and take up an unnecessary amount of space in your database.

Comment: I know this method but our professor said use database to store the pictures :/

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.